# Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring unknown module "104"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, charts, highcharts

I have installed React Native Highcharts but while importing the module:

```
import HighchartsReactNative from '@highcharts/highcharts-react-native';
```

Getting error Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring  unknown module "104". If you are sure the module exists, try restarting Metro. You may also want ti run 'Yarn' or 'npm install' importing the module I got the above error.

I have already restarted the Metro bundler and restarted many times but did not worked.

Comment: try removing node modules, and then re install dependencies

Comment: @LonelyCpp I have already did that but unfortunately not worked.

Comment: Do you have all the required prerequisites for Highcharts?

    node 11.2+
    npm 6.7.0+ or similar package manager
    React 16.4+
    React native 0.59.3+


https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native#general-prerequisites

Comment: @p-syche Yes I have double checked.

Comment: The probelm can be related with other issue, reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react-native/issues/39 Please try to use solutions introduced by third party developers.

Comment: try `watchman watch-del-all` and stop remote debugging and restart metro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Ensure the module is installed by checking the folder `node_modules/@highcharts/highcharts-react-native`

  - If it is missing, install it with `yarn add @highcharts/highcharts-react-native` or `npm install --save @highcharts/highcharts-react-native`
- Clear metro cache with `watchman watch-del-all` and `rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-*`
- Restart the bundler resetting the cache with `yarn start --reset-cache` or `npm run start --reset-cache`
- Reload the bundle in your app (shake and press `Restart` on the menu)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to clear Metro cache. Please take a look [to this gist](https://gist.github.com/jarretmoses/c2e4786fd342b3444f3bc6beff32098d).

Hope this helps.